# Finding the Angle Between Directions of the Two Paths.

Tags: trigonometry

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> A plane hillside is inclined at an angle of $28 ^o$ with the horizontal. A man wearing skis can climb this hillside by following a straight path 
>   inclined at an angle of $12^o$ to the horizontal but one without skis must follow a path inclined at an angle of only $5 ^o$ wth the horizontal.
>   Find the angle between directions of the two paths.

My work:

I imagined the problem like this:

[image: (picture)]

The angle colored by a yellow color is the angle between directions of the two paths. It seems easy, because I can get the third angle indicated as a yellow color 
by noting that the complement of $12^o$ is $168^o$. Then the triangle created by red, green and brown lines has an angle of $5^o-168^o-7^o$ triangle.

Threfore, the angle between directions of the two paths is $7^o$. But I still have doubts about the answer because of my belief that if it seems easy, you're doing 
it wrong.

Is my answer correct? I couldn't verify it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Both have to climb the 28 degree slope. So what they do is instead of going straight up, they go sideways. This is a 3D geometry problem, not a 2D one. I think this should be enough of a hint

[image]

Dotted lines are in the horizontal plane. Any solid lines are in the plane at $28^o$. Red trajectory is for the person with the skis. The person walking can either go on the same side (green trajectory) or opposite side (blue trajectory). The angle between the red and dotted red line is $12^o$. The angle between green and dotted green lines, or blue and dotted blue, is $5^o$

Comment: Wait...if you describe it that way, what is the figure look like? Because I  imagine many figures that could fit the description in the problem. For example: The $5^o$ slope ramp is on the left, the $28^o$ slope is on middle and the $12^o$ slope is on the right.

Comment: I have a plane that makes a $28 ^o$ with the horizontal. Suppose the origin is on the intersection line between this plane and the horizontal. Now take two lines from the origin, going up the plane, but not straight up. They will have a smaller slope. You have several cases, but they can all be grouped into two categories: 1. Both trajectories on the same side. 2. trajectories on opposite sides

Comment: I've added a picture to my reply

Comment: "The angle between the red and dotted red line is $12^o$. The angle between green and dotted green lines, or blue and dotted blue, is $5^o$."